# Why does the height of the div set to 200px when the height is not set explicitly anywhere?

Tags: css, height, css-position

I have the following code where a div is absolutely positioned inside a relative container. The relative div's `height` is set as `0` and `padding-bottom` to `100%` since the inner content will be dynamically loaded and hence the outer-container's dimensions are to be maintained.

My Inner div has many `div`elements whose height crosses the height of the outer div however the height of the outer div is set with the value same as the width.

CSS:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.right-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
.my-frame-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.my-frame-content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right-modal">
      <div class="my-frame-container">
        <div class="my-frame-content">
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
          <div class="box"> Hello </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how did the height of the div `my-frame-container` in the code has the value 200px.

Here is the [link](https://jsbin.com/tidipot/edit?html,css,output) to the js bin.

To be precise, I haven't set the height explicitly to 200px in any of my styling, but still why does the height of the div `my-frame-container` and `my-frame-content` set to 200px.

[image: Here the height is set to 342px]
[image: Here the height is restricted to 200px. Why and How is my question.]

Comment: Don't understand the question. What do you need help with?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? If you mean "why does the inspector say the height of my-frame-container is 200px in the tooltip thingy", the answer is because the tooltip thingy adds the height and padding properties.

Comment: @Naomi I have updated the question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, it's because the browser adds the values for `height` and `padding` together when showing the size in the pop up tooltip.

If you were to look at the styles in the developer tools section below, it does mention 200 × 0 there for the size and 200 for the padding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its because you set that div under another div with class right-modal which you gave the height  200 px

Comment: I haven't set `height` to the class `right-modal`. Only width. Is height auto calculated based on width?

Comment: Yes just change the width to 0 and you will see nothing on the screen